# How can I keep processes running on a remote server even after turning off the terminal machine?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, nohup, remote-management

..and then still be able to return to the same session/screen after restarting the terminal machine.
I've tried screen but once I restarted my computer screen -d showed no sessions. Nohup seems to be what I want, but then I lose the ability to see the output later on, other than by saving it to a file. Cannot I pretend more?

Answer (score 5):

Screen should work fine. Give more details about what you are doing. 
Common commands:

```
# reattach session and if necessary detach it first.
# If there is only one session, sessionname is not necessary.
$ screen -rd sessionname

# list available screen sessions
$ screen -ls
```

I am not sure why you are using

```
$ screen -d
```

All this does is detach a screen session, provided there is only one. Otherwise it will ask which one you want to detach.

I also find

```
$ echo $TERM
```

useful to show whether I am actually inside a screen or not, since this is not always obvious. If in a screen, it will return `screen`. If there are better ways to do this, I'd like to know about them.

Comment: $ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/folders/Am/AmQYwuIoFSO0BNhXmOGzQU+++TI/-Tmp-/.screen.
But I had detached sessions before turning off my machine, how do I attach to them again now?

Comment: @simpatico: Strange. It wouldn't actually matter whether you detached the sessions before turning off your local machine, as long as they were running on the remote machine. You are certain you are running this command on the remote machine and that the earlier screen sessions were on the remote machine? (No offense intended.) I suggest you take a few minutes and try it again.

Comment: @simpatico: by the way, if you want someone to be notified of your comment, prefix it with @username.

Comment: I execute $ screen -ls on my terminal. Before $ screen -d == $ screen ls, since I had multiple screens. N offense, is there how I could execute the command with some log to prove/track things?

Comment: @simpatico: not following all of the comment,sorry. You can enable log for a screen session from inside the session with `C-a H'. See the documentation. Again, prefix if you want someone to be notified of your comment.

Comment: @Faheem: I still don't get it to work. I connect to the remote server through ssh and when I connect back to it from my home through vpn screen ls prints what I pasted in the 1st comment

Comment: @simpatico: please post a minimal complete transcript of your ssh and/or vpn logins and screen sessions, including all commands you type.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you were on the right way, `screen` is what you want and not `nohup`. As you said with `nohup` you cannot <del>change the settings</del> get your environment back after logging out the remote server. `screen` supports that. Look in this [tutorial](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/). Basically what you need is:

```
ssh machine
screen
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>

```
yourcommand
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

```
exit
ssh machine
screen -ls
10176.blahblah  (blah)  (Detached)
screen -r 10176
```

Comment: In general, `screen -DR` is the simplest way to reattach your last session.

Comment: Sure, but it's nice to demonstrate `screen -ls` because he will need it at some point after starting creating many sessions on the remote server :)